# S-function MATLAB simulink flag=0

Tags: matlab, controller, logic, simulink, fuzzy

I'M getting Below error
in `'STLF/Fuzzy Logic Controller with Ruleviewer/Animation1'` while executing MATLAB S-function `'animrule', flag = 0 (initialize)`, at start of simulation.

Comment: Hello Fabulous! Please, describe more details about what is going on.

Comment: This is actually the error I get whenever I run the program. Error in 'STLF/Fuzzy Logic  Controller  with Ruleviewer/Animation1' while executing MATLAB S-function 'animrule', flag = 0 (initialize), at start of simulation.

Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.

Comment: I'm working on STLF using fuzzy logic in MATLAB and using Simulink for simulation. After designing the model and run it, then the above error will be displayed